# Porting Java code to C#

Tags: c#, java, porting

I need to create a porting software that will convert Java code to C# (and vice verse, but I will look into that after). The software will aim at people who are proficient in one language and know completely nothing about the other one, and also if you have a very good piece of source code on one platform and want to use it on another without having to manually change it.

I know there are existing works similar to this, but I need to create my own (also for practice purposes), and I'm not really sure how to start. I have considered making a C# project which will call a .Java source code, and go through it line by line and convert the text to what C# looks like. Example: public class Car extends Vehicle {} change to public class Car : Vehicle {} and go on about changing every difference between the two languages.

Is this the proper approach and are there any other ones?

*Note: I have found articles about it, and I saw AST and Parsing come out a lot, as well as several parsers such as NRefactory. Can anyone explain how are those terms related to my problem, and how does a parser(NRefactory) works? The definitions gave me an overview, but I'm still not sure if I understand the concept.

Comment: It's harder than just porting language syntax and semantics, there're features that you'll find in Java and missing in .NET and viceversa. Some tend to think .NET is a Java clone, but actually both are different monsters... Anyway, I'm pretty sure the best way of porting Java to C# is working directly with byte code of both platforms.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer So how would I go about using the byte code to convert between the two?

Comment: I suggest you that because if you port code to .NET you need to compile it into bytecode too, and I believe that it should be easier to build an assembly directly with bytecode generated by some Java parser/interpreter... But it seems you want a near to impossible thing...

Comment: Do you need to convert Java source (text) to C# source (text) or do you also want to generate the byte code/execute the code? A first step would be to generate a Parser for the needed Grammar to provide an AST. While generating source code (text) out of the AST, generating byte code gets more complex. I had to dig into the same topic myself, and made good experience with javacc and CoCo/R (implementation for lots of programming languages available)

Comment: If I can convert the text analogies of the source codes, it would be great. Right now I am aiming for that, because if I have the source code, I can paste it inside the compiler (not the most efficient way, but it would satisfy me for now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java has features that don't exist in C# and C# has features that don't exist in Java so a simple one to one correspondence conversion is impossible.

Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Java) to see where you'll start running into problems.

A parser is necessary to properly convert syntax of one language which doesn't exist in another, so you'll essentially need to build an [interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29) which is not a trivial project.

Compilers, like interpreters are based on a syntax parser. You can find lots of good tutorials and resources online for compiler constructions by google search. For example, [here](http://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/) is a good one.

Comment: That comparison article doesn't show a lot of differences. 80% of the table is green. And I don't understand why I need an interpreter. If you say a parser is what properly converts a syntax, then what I was initially planning to make was a parser. If the parser works, I will have working C# source code, which I can just copy paste into my project.

Comment: The wikipedia article posted shows many important differences between C# and Java. A parser returns a parse tree which you'll need to convert back into source code.

Comment: So correct me if I'm wrong: Java source code --> Parser --> Converts to something independent of a language (parse tree) --> Parse (any desired language)?

Comment: But what is a more in depth process? I pass the Java source code into the parser. What does it do with it? How does he do it? What is the format of the outputted AST? How is it read by the second parser? If you know a great source where I can read about it, it would be greatly appreciated :)